# Can i override loglevel in log4net?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

is it possible to override the standard log levels? My problem is that I need syslog levels like DEBUG = 100 and not DEBUG = 30000 as defined by log4net.
Are the LogLevel removed via LevelMap.Clear ()?

More Details:
We use in a PHP Project the monolog library. Now we need a tool that we want develop in C#. For logging in C# i would use log4net. So both Apps shold write logevents in the same logfile. In monolog we use RotatingFileHandler and in log4net we use the RollingFileAppender.

It works fine but monolog have loglevels like Debug = 100 and by log4net is the loglevel value for Debug = 30000.

Is it posible to edit the value. or can override some Methods?

Sorry for my bad english i hope u understand me.

thanks for reply.

Comment: There's no "standard" log level. You specify the level when you log a message using methods like `Error`, `Info`, etc. Post your code

Comment: Are you asking how to *change* the value used to represent the log level in some appender that *doesn't* use strings for this? What appender are you using? How is it configured?

Comment: RemoteSyslogAppender uses a PatternLayout to create format strings just like other appenders. What pattern did you use? Why did *numbers* end up in there instead of INFO, WARN, DEBUG?

Comment: You can [look at the source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Core/LevelMap.cs)

Comment: Ok. I have edit my question. I hope someone can give me a hint.

Comment: Still not sure why it matters, are you outputting the level to a file? If so add a custom appender (that extends rolling file appender) that changes/swaps the value for each log level.

Comment: @Igor So the monolog FileRotatingHandler format the logevents with LogstashFormatter and a logstash instance push the events to ElasticSearch. And the same mechanism we want for the C# App. For this we need the same format.